# Update value through textbox after fetching them from database NOT WORKING

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

We are fetching values from database and showing them textboxes while page is loaded then while updating, the click event of that page not working and gets redirected to master page automatically. We need to update those fetched value in database.

```
public partial class pages_update : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"].ToString());
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {

            // txtname.Text = this.txtname.Text;
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=studreg;Integrated Security=True");
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader iReader = null;

            /*
            if (id != 0)
            {
                if (!this.IsPostBack)
                {
                txtname.Text = id;
                //msg_lbl.Text = "Inside not PostBack";
            }
        }
        else
            Response.Write("Invalid URL for article");
        */


        string images = Request.QueryString["image1"];
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select id,(cast(fname as varchar(10))+''+cast(mname as varchar(10))+''+cast(lname as varchar(10)))as concatenated ,qualification,collage,dob,image,address,contact,email, technology from studreg", connection);
        iReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        int status = 0;
        while (iReader.Read())
        {
            int chkid = int.Parse(iReader["id"].ToString()); ;

            if (id == chkid && status == 0)
            {
                status = 1;
                // txtid.Text = (iReader["id"].ToString());
                txtname.Text = (iReader["concatenated"].ToString());
                txtqualification.Text = (iReader["qualification"].ToString());
                txtcollage.Text = (iReader["collage"].ToString());
                //  txtgender.Text = (iReader["gender"].ToString());
                txtdob.Text = (iReader["dob"].ToString());
                string path = string.Concat(@"/internship/pages/images/", iReader["image"].ToString());
                Image1.ImageUrl = path;
                txtaddress.Text = (iReader["address"].ToString());
                txtcontact.Text = (iReader["contact"].ToString());
                txtemail.Text = (iReader["email"].ToString());
                txttechnology.Text = (iReader["technology"].ToString());
             //   break;
            } //end if
        } // end while

    } // ennd ispostback

} // page load
//  connection.Close();




//protected void UPDATE_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
protected void UPDATE_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=studreg;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update studreg set qualification=@qualification,collage=@collage,dob=@dob,address=@address,contact=@contact,email=@email,technology=@technology where id=@id", connection);

        if (connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            connection.Open();
            // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@concatenated", txtname.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qualification", txtqualification.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@collage", txtcollage.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", txtdob.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", txtaddress.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contact", txtcontact.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtemail.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@technology", txttechnology.Text);
            //   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txtid.Text);*/
            //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
            //  lblmsg.Text = "Successfully updated";
        }
        else
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

### Button:

```
<asp:Button ID="UPDATE" class="btn btn-info pull-right" runat="server" Text="UPDATE" onClick="UPDATE_Click" ></asp:Button>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with mvc or web-api.

Comment: You don't supply a value for `id` in your `SqlCommand`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, you didn't add `@id` parameter value you defined on `WHERE` part as `where id = @id`. Looks like you need to uncomment that line;

```
// cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txtid.Text);*/
```

Or delete the `@id` parameter in your command if it is unnecessary.

A few things more;

- Use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection and command automatically instead of calling `Close` method manually.
- Don't use `AddWithValue` as much as possible. [It *may* generate unexpected results sometimes](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use `Add` method overload to specify your parameter type and it's size.

```
using(var connection = new SqlConnection(conStr))
using(var cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    // Define your CommandText
    // Add your parameter values with Add method
    // Open your connection
    // Execute your query 
}
```

*Be aware*, you add your all parameters as a text. Based on it's name, `id` column should be numeric typed, not character.

Comment: we have passed id through url and displayed the one which matches that id.see the checking part(id -> passed through url and chkid-> getting from database) whenever matched we are displaying the data. and we want that data to be modified based on id on update button click. id modification not needed.

Comment: @JasithaUday I don't understand your comment. Can you please clarify it?

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/24et0k1/9 please check the url. i have attached a screenshot and also explained what i am trying to do. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @JasithaUday I can not open the image since I'm at work now. Put your all information inside to your question.

Comment: i have a form where i am fetching  details of employee based on id and populating it into textboxes inside the form.We are passing id through url Ex - http://localhost:55920/internship/pages/update.aspx?id=12. Now i want employee details to be modified by the update button.